# Error codes with variable String descriptions in Java

Tags: java, enums

I would like to have error codes in my Java project, but they should have variable String descriptions. For example, I might have two BadCharacterCount errors, but I'd like to represent them as two different strings, e.g. "Bad character count: expected 50, got 60" and "Bad character count: expected 40, got 70." I'd like to be able to recognize both of these cases as BadCharacterCount errors, and ideally have these in an enum of some sort.

There's a nice discussion of a similar problem here:
[Best way to define error codes/strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446663/best-way-to-define-error-codes-strings-in-java)

However, they don't deal with the case of variable error Strings... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your two error descriptions:

> Bad character count: expected 50, got 60

And:

> Bad character count: expected 40, got 70.

Are already the same.  The string is:

> Bad character count: expected %s, got %s.

Then when you need to *construct* the error message, just make sure to pass it through `String.format`:

```
String.Format(Error.BadCharacterCount, 50, 60)
```

And

```
String.Format(Error.BadCharacterCount, 40, 70)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the error string as a format for String.format().  Of course, you then have to be careful to have your arguments for each error line up correctly with the particular format.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this:

```
public class BadCharacterCountException extends Exception {
    public BadCharacterCountException(int expected, int recieved) {
       super("Bad character count: expected " + expected + ", got " + recieved + ".");
    }
}
```

or

```
public enum ErrorCode {
    BadCharacterCount("Bad character count: expected {0}, got {1}.");

    private final String message;
    private ErrorCode(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage(Object... args) {
        return MessageFormat.format(message, args);
    }
}
```