# Sharing constants between projects

Tags: java, constants, project-structure

I have java two projects; one server project and one client project. In my network code between the two, I send requests. I don't want to type 0, 1, 2 for the different types of requests in the code, so I use constants instead. My problem is that I don't want to declare these constants in both projects, but rather at one place, since the constants are the same for both projects. Does anyone know a good solution for this?

Edit: The client project is an android application and the server is a servlet which should handle requests from clients.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a library project with an Interface. This interface declares the constants. Share this library in both projects. If you use some dependency management as in maven this is quite easy.

EDIT:

Using a final Class as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface is better! But the core is, to use a library project and share the common part of both projects in a separate jar.

Comment: Doing this is a bad practice, see _Constant Interface Antipattern, Effective Java, Item 17_

Comment: ... or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659593/what-is-the-use-of-interface-constants)

Comment: @user714965 Only **implementing** that interface is bad practice, really. But writing a final, noninstantiable class is still better as it makes it impossible to do the bad thing.

Comment: Yes, using a interface to define the constants is not the best thing, I know. But the core point is to use a lib and share this lib. Alternatives: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface

Comment: Ah, thanks everyone, I'll try to make a library project and use the final class.

Comment: I would create an enum with no instances. This is implicitly final with a private constructor. Some consider this a hack. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your architecture but if the client makes calls to the server you have a dependency here already.

So you should add the server project as a dependency in your client project. Then you can define a class (or maybe an enum in your case) in the server project which contains the constants. This is where it belongs as the server provides those method.