# implement class or import class java

Tags: java, class, interface, import

Internally for Java what is better, or what is optimal, or What is the standard: implement a class with constants or using dot notation?

Example:

**Option 1:**

```
import com.myproject.Constantes;

public class myClass {
    myClass() {
        System.out.println("Math: " + Constantes.PI);
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
import com.myproject.Constantes;

public class myClass implements Constantes {

    myClass() {
        System.out.println("Math: " + PI);
    }
}
```

Which is better and why? MVJ use, resources, speed?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49572/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-have-an-interface-to-define-constants

Comment: neither one nor two. i dont like both solutions. with this you will have alwys a direct dependency to this constants class. put the constants to the class where they belong to technically/functional

Comment: @resTive It looks like that class really needs that PI there. So how would you eliminate that dependency with your #3?

Comment: static imports are optimal in several ways I guess..

Comment: Implementing an interface to get access to constants is called the [constant interface antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659593/what-is-the-use-of-interface-constants). The name "antipattern" suggests that this is bad practice.

Comment: @full.stack.ex in *this* simple example i would deliver the constant as value. i thought about your question and yes my answer was overall too much simplified. But until now i cant remember where i should have used one great constant class.

Comment: @resTive Math.PI, or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html to name a few ;). You are right; just a bit too much generalization.

Comment: @Rp, that's debatable. They bring no advantage at runtime, no practical advantage at compile time (shorten the code a little), they make it harder to find where the constant belongs to, and they introduce subtle issues as per LuigiEdlCarno's answer.

Comment: @full.stack.ex the class Math is an utility class all around mathematical operations. so my argument "constants should be owned by their technically/functional class" still applies. The class JFrame of the swing api is another example.  As counterpart you may field org.eclipse.swt.SWT or your Android R class. so _i think_ its mainly a personal decision, and my is like "big constant-only classes are bad design".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `Constantes` is purely a collection of constants (as the name implies) and doesn't define functionality that you need to expose in `myClass`, then A) It shouldn't be an `interface`, and B) You shouldn't implement/extend it. Import it and use it as in Option 1.

Comment: actually, I've found an interface that only has constants varied. belongs to no structure, no methods, only variables. It's like a drawer disaster.

And I've found a class that implements that interface but is repeated more than 100 times the code "Constantes.name_constant" and I thought "better implement and replace all that code repeated (Constantes.name_constant) and left alone (name_constant)".

Comment: @user1782602: It's your decision. I wouldn't, I'd leave the `Constantes.name_constant` usage in the code. It's nice and clear, for one thing, and it doesn't say your class implements something that it doesn't really implement. In terms of the JVM, I don't think it cares one way or the other.

Comment: Understood, must respect a model and make good use of the class hierarchy. Here are misusing and I agree with your way of doing it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I think OPTION 1 should be used to avoid mistaking another PI defined internally in the current class.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 should be used, because this will definetly use the constant defined in the imported class.

If you had a local variable called PI in myClass, Option 2 would you that variable, instead of the one in the imported class.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing two different things here. In the first fragment you're just writing code that happens to reference stuff in the `Constantes` class/interface and thus needs to be `import`'ed whereas in the second fragment, you're stating the your code must conform to the `Constantes` interface, i.e. implementing any and all methods therein.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

`implements` (an interface, not a class) says that `myClass` must honour the contract specified by `Constantes` (usually with some method specifications that must be implemented in your class).

Please, check about Object Oriented Programming (Programación Orientada a Objetos) concepts before getting into the particularities of any given language.

Comment: actually, I've found an interface that only has constants varied. belongs to no structure, no methods, only variables. It's like a drawer disaster.

And I've found a class that implements that interface but is repeated more than 100 times the code "Constantes.name_constant" and I thought "better implement and replace all that code repeated (Constantes.name_constant) and left alone (name_constant)".

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. Then Peter Lawrey's answer should be the correct, mark it as such.

Comment: No, your answer is correct. I understand perfectly and try to apply it. I'm trying to improve this project gradually Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Often clarity is more important than performance and this is no exception.

Option 1 is preferred to option 2 as the latter implies that `myClass` is a `Constantes` which doesn't make sense.

Since Java 5.0 you have another option which may be better.

```
import static com.myproject.Constantes.PI;
// OR
import static com.myproject.Constantes.*;

public class MyClass{
  MyClass(){
       System.out.println("Math: " + PI);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm done with a project 1.4: (I'm afraid I can not change it but I'm also in another 1.5 and try to apply it, I did not know that this could be done.

Comment: Its worth nothing that the End of Public Updates for Java 6 has been extends to Feb 2013. https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/java_6_eol_h_h  If you get a chance to update, I would seriously consider Java 7 not Java 5.0.