# When is it correct to declare variables within an interface in Java?

Tags: java, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the use of interface constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659593/what-is-the-use-of-interface-constants)

I am creating a calculator program inside Eclipse EE and wanted to know if it would be
correct to write interfaces within the project and also when would it ever be necessary or
fitting to declare variable within an interface in Java?

Also, I wanted to know if I should create an abstract class within my calculator program
My calculator program follows the basic model-view-controller pattern.

Comment: A variable within an interface will be a static constant by default.

Comment: This question will have different answers when Java 8 is released.

Comment: @Perception I don't think it will change the semantics of interface variables, will it?

Comment: @assylias - at the last state of interface default methods there was discussion on the need for non-static interface variables. But that spec is still in flux so it might not make it into final.

Comment: The decision whether to use interfaces and abstract classes is complex and depends on the design of the application being written. Your description of the calculator is insufficient to make that determination.

Comment: @Perception you can add virtual extensions to interfaces in Java 8, but you will cannot have anything but `public static final` fields.

Answer (score 4):

All variables in an interface are static constants. Although you are not writing it explicitly, they are still public, static and final.

This in an interface

```
String msg = "Please enter value : "
```

is the same as

```
public final static String msg = "Please enter value : "
```

Generally all the constants are kept in a Interface and used all over the project by interface_name.variable name.

Comment: even "public static final String" :D

Comment: The above question and the replies are fine. But, using an interface to declare constants is not recommended. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-constants-in-java

Comment: @javausersoma seeing at the link, first answer is saying that don't use its "OWN" class or interface to define the constants. What ever he gave example that though object is constant, its state not. For this u can create immutable objects by making members and private and not providing setter methods instead of that create a parameterized constructor.