# Android - change the language in Android Application not working

Tags: android, localization

I am trying to do localization to my android application. The error message is not changed unless i force stop the app and start it after the language is changed.

```
public interface ApplicationConstants {

Resources res = MyActivity.getInstance().getAppContext().getResources();
public static final String NETWORK_ERROR_MESS=res.getString(R.string.str_network_error);
public static final String AUTH_ERR=res.getString(R.string.str_auth_error);

 }
```

In `res-> values` folder

**Strings.xml**

```
 <string name="str_network_error"> Network Error english.</string>
<string name="str_auth_error">Authentication failure english.</string>
```

In `res-> values-fr` folder

**Strings.xml**

```
 <string name="str_network_error"> Network Error france.</string>
<string name="str_auth_error">Authentication failure france.</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way: when your main activity load

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fr");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

And get the `String` in your activity like

```
String NETWORK_ERROR_MESS=youractivity.this.getString(R.string.str_network_error);
String AUTH_ERR=youractivity.this.getString(R.string.str_auth_error);
```

Comment: I have tried to set the local language and my code is reaching that particular part of the code, so now the language is set. But still the message is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, all your problems appears due incorrect use of interfaces.
For more information read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659740/186891)

Comment: i am following the procedure as specified in the solution of the link you have provided.