# Declare constant in interface, but define in implementation

Tags: java, groovy, constants

I want to be able to do something akin to the following

```
public interface myInterface{
    public final String MY_CONST
}

public class myImpl implements myInterface{
     MY_CONST="Hello World"
}
```

Basically, I want to declare a constant in my interface, and define it in my implementation. Is there a way to do something like this in java/groovy?

Comment: No. And anyway, [*the constant interface pattern is a poor use of interfaces*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2659740/1225328).

Comment: No. All fields in Java interfaces are implicitly `static` and `final`, the latter preventing assignment delegation to implementing classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `traits` in Groovy with similar effect:

```
trait WithConstant {
    final String VALUE = "tim"
}

class MyClass implements WithConstant {
    final String VALUE = "steve"

    def print() {
        println VALUE
    }
}

new MyClass().print()
```

Answer (score 7):

In Java, the closest you can come is a getter:

```
public interface myInterface{
    String getConstant();
}

public class myImpl implements myInterface{
     public String getConstant() {
        return "Hellow world";
     }
}
```

...since interfaces can't have instance fields.

Comment: You should maybe declare `getConstant()` final  in the child class otherwise it could be overrided.

Comment: @davidxxx: Well, if the value isn't defined by the interface, it's not clear whether it's a problem or a goal that it can be overridden in a subclass.

Comment: I agree with it is not clear but If it is a goal that the value to be redefined (so more than once), the need has not really relation with the constant concept.