# Enum for key name and value

Tags: java

I want to use Enum as a key value. I tired this:

```
public interface ElementTypeEnum
{
    public static String QUEUE_TRANSACTION = "queue_transaction";

    public static String QUEUE_API_ATTEMPT = "queue_api_attempt";
}
```

but when I tried to use it this way: `QUEUE_TRANSACTIONs cannot be resolved or is not a field`

What is the proper way to use it?

Comment: How and where did you try to use it? Also notice that `QUEUE_TRANSACTIONs`, has an extra `s`

Comment: Where is the enum you are talking about? This is currently an Interface with two static fields.

Comment: `enum` with `private string key` can actually help you to enclose more details.

Comment: These are `String` types, I don't see an enum

Comment: also declaring constants in an interface is a common anti-pattern

Answer (score 1):

Enum and interface are two different concepts in general, so you need to read :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

[What are enums and why are they useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709175/what-are-enums-and-why-are-they-usefu)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

[What is the use of interface constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659593/what-is-the-use-of-interface-constants)