# Create interface for constant

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interfaces with static fields in java for sharing ‘constants’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320588/interfaces-with-static-fields-in-java-for-sharing-constants)

We have constants that we need to use in lot of class and my question 
is if its best practice to create interface with public attribute 
or something else...

```
public static final String NAME = "Name";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-** First of all answering you question in one breath...Yes its possible, **infact if you use**

`public int x=5;` **Or**

`int x=5` ,

**this will always be interpreted as** `public static final int x=5;`

**-** But this is **Not the Right way** to do it.

**-** You can better use `Enum` or `Class with Private Constructor`  to handle this.

**Eg:**

**Class with a static field:**

```
   public class Test{


       public final String NAME = "Name";

       private Test(){}


      }

}
```

Comment: There's no need to instantiate a class that only holds constants.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd  You are absolutely right, But i would like to throw light over this that `"A class with static methods and static fields are equivalent to Sigleton Class", But this should Not be used, as the loading of which class and when by JVM is not a definite process. So Singleton is a safe bet.`

Comment: Safe but superfluous. Your singleton doesn't even hold the constant field, so it's utterly pointless. Also: it's good practice to make a singleton class final

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd i think u missed the constant field NAME in my code... please it properly

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Moreover if you read it once again carefully, you will come to know that i have also suggested the use of Enum... but provided example of Singleton....

Comment: Kumar, I did read your code properly, the thing is: the `NAME` field is static, and hence not a member of your singleton. Of course you *could* access it as `Test.getInstance().NAME`, but any reasonable IDE would warn you that you should change access to a static field to static access, i.e. `Test.NAME`. Your class has a constant and a singleton, but those two are totally unrelated, and therefor the singleton is unnecessary in the context of this question.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd i understood what you meant to say.... thanks for getting the smoke cleared.. I have changed the answer accordingly...

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd and it was nice to meet a guy who has a martial arts background. I have myself practiced Wing-Tsun.

Answer (score 7):

You should use a non-instanstiatable class for this, not an interface.

```
public final class Constants{

  private Constants(){}

  public static final String NAME = "Name";

  // more constants


}
```

Interfaces should define behavior only, according to Joshua Bloch in [Effective Java](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=0321356683):

> **The constant interface pattern is a poor use of interfaces.** That a
>   class uses some constants internally is an implementation detail.
>   Implementing a constant interface causes this implementation detail to
>   leak into the class’s exported API. It is of no consequence to the
>   users of a class that the class implements a constant interface. In
>   fact, it may even confuse them. Worse, it represents a commitment: if
>   in a future release the class is modified so that it no longer needs
>   to use the con- stants, it still must implement the interface to
>   ensure binary compatibility. If a nonfinal class implements a constant
>   interface, all of its subclasses will have their namespaces polluted
>   by the constants in the interface.

Source: Effective Java, Item 19: Use interfaces only to define types

Comment: Thanks for your answer!do you think that using final class is better than using enum for constants ? Thank you!

Comment: @FedorE If you have the possibility to work with enums, that is preferable, but if you need String constants, enums can't provide them.

Answer (score 1):

Well my suggestion would be to create a class for a constants. Not an interface, if the interface has no methods then it is not serving it's purpose.

> Placing constants in an interface was a popular technique in the early
>   days of Java, but now many consider it a distasteful use of
>   interfaces, since interfaces should deal with the services provided by
>   an object, not its data. As well, the constants used by a class are
>   typically an implementation detail, but placing them in an interface
>   promotes them to the public API of the class.

Take a look [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=32).

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid of using such constants in an interface. You can go with solution proposed by Sean Patrick Floyd. Or use enum type for your constants.

```
public enum Constants {
 NAME("Name");

 private final String constant; 

 private Constats(String constat) {
   this.constant = constant;
 }

 public String constant(){ 
   return this.constat; 
 }

}
```

When your code needs them you should use the enum type. Then you will have order in your code.

Comment: I would agree with the enum solution, but unfortunately, an enum's member is not a compile-time constant, i.e. it can't be used in an annotation value, for example. Unfortunately there is no compile-time-constant way to get a String from an enum

Comment: You are right. Good that you point that out. I wrote it because it may look that OP or other developer do not need the compile-time constant but only a place where he can store a place holder to String values that is reaused in code.