# The field is ambiguous while it is clearly hidden

Tags: java, hide, constants, ambiguity

I know and fully agree that sharing constants through interfaces is considered as a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/320642/1225328), but I didn't choose this implementation. Whatever:

```java
interface SuperClassConstants {
    public static final String CONSTANT = "super";
}

interface SubClassConstants extends SuperClassConstants {
    public static final String CONSTANT = "sub";
}

class SuperClass implements SuperClassConstants {
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass implements SubClassConstants {
    public SubClass() {
        System.out.println(CONSTANT);
        // The field CONSTANT is ambiguous
    }
}
```

Why *ambiguous*? Isn't the constant hidden? I thought Java would have understood I was expecting `"sub"`...

Comment: But your `SubClass` class can access to both interfaces...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [JLS 9.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#d5e12665):

> If two fields with the same name are inherited by an interface because, for example, two of its direct superinterfaces declare fields with that name, then a single ambiguous member results. Any use of this ambiguous member will result in a compile-time error.

The field `CONSTANT` in `SubClassConstants` has hidden the `CONSTANT` of `SuperClassConstants`. But the class `SubClass` has access to both the `CONSTANT` as it virtually implements both the interfaces.

You can remove the ambiguity by specifying the Interface name :

```
System.out.println(SubClassConstants.CONSTANT);
```

Also read [JLS 6.5.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.1):

> If an expression name consists of a single Identifier, then there must be exactly one declaration denoting either a local variable, parameter, or field visible (§6.4.1) at the point at which the Identifier occurs. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.