# Is it good to Sharing constant strings in Java across many classes?

Tags: java, readability

I'd like to have Java constant strings at one place and use them across whole project?I am confusing Is it a good practice for better readability or not?

Comment: It is an opinion-based question.

Comment: No particular issues as you said they will be constants(hope they are not in large numbers), else could be implemented using props file or might be Enums for clarity and maintainability aspects (you save declaring strings values).

Comment: Do you think it makes sense to?

Comment: if that is a constant the you are not sharing anything, all modules are just using that constant... and yes, it is ok, is the same you do when "share" Locale.CANADA or Color.Azure....

Comment: If strings have important role in some API, protocols this practice is widely accepted `public final String CATEGORY = "Category";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that your Strings are going to be referenced in many flows, then it is good to use. Moreover, it is a widely accepted practice as well.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: when multiple classes need the same information, then that information should have a single "root".

So yes: it is absolutely *good* practice to avoid re-declaring the same value in different places. Having a "global" constant simply helps with avoiding code duplication - thus preventing errors *later on*, when you might have to change such values.

Answer (score 2):

One single class with (unrelated) constants has problems. It is a **bottleneck**:
if in a team a constant is added at the bottom, someone else adding a constant will receive a VCS conflict. *Enforce the declarations to be sorted alphabetically.* It also ties this package together in other forms. Still many unneeded recompilations would be needed (see also the remark at the end).

In **java 9 with modules**, you would in every using module need to `require` the constants classes module, probably causing an unnecessary module graph.

Then there are constants which need not be named and still are not "magic".
In annotations as arguments. An annotation scanning can gather those values if you need uniqueness or such.

And finally there are shared constants. **Near the used constructs** is still my favourite.

Also the constants class pattern tends to be used often with String constants. That reeks of code smell, as it is a kind of burocracy where one
should use **automatic mechanisms**, OO, fixed conventions, declarative data.

For database tables and columns there exist better mechanisms.

Classes with constants (still) have the **technical compilation problem** that in java the constant is incorporated in the .class file itself, and the import disappears. Hence changing the original constant will not notify the compiler to recompile the "using" class. One needs a full clean build after recompiling a constants class.

Answer (score 1):

It is good to create Interface & declare your all constant in it.
E.G

```
public interface ICommonConstants {
    public static final String ENCODING_TYPE_UTF8="UTF-8";
}
```

Implement this interface in your all class where you like to use constants.You can use by calling

```
ICommonConstants.ENCODING_TYPE_UTF8
```

Comment: This is bad practice. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320588/interfaces-with-static-fields-in-java-for-sharing-constants

Comment: @SpaceTrucker The bad practice is implementing that interface, using an interface for constants instead of a class is not really different (and it is shorter because you don't need to add `public static final`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel But by putting the constants in an interface instead of a class you make it easier for consumers to make this mistake. And since we should strive for code that makes an incorrect usage as difficult as possible, the pattern should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Code duplication is a *code smell* and if you wouldn't use readily available constants you need to re-declare the String over and over again for each class using it, which is bad.

This leads to less maintainable code, because when the duplicated String needs to change and you forget to update it in one of the classes, the code breaks.

It's common practice to set up a class holding reusable constants:

```
public final class MyDefs {
    public static final String A = "a";
    public static final String B = "b";

    private MyDefs() {
        // Utility class, don't initialize.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend an `Enum`, or you could just have sort of like a utility class with just static final strings. All depends on what you want do i guess, i don't see anything bad. if the class is going to be shared by many classes, that's fine.